# When does $\int_0^t dX_s = X_t-X_0$ hold for a stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

So I am learning stochastic calculus and I have seen this relationship be used many times:
$$
\int_0^t dX_s = X_t-X_0
$$
where $X_t$ is some stochastic process.

It looks like some sort of application of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but is it? And does this hold for any stochastic process?

Comment: What is the definition of stochastic integral you are working with?

Comment: Just apply your definition and see that you have a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of an Itō stochastic integral
$ \int_0^t H_s \; dX_s$ (with respect to a semimartingale $X_t$) is the limit of
$\sum_{j=1}^n H_{t_{j-1}} (X_{t_j} - X_{t_{j-1}})$ for partitions
$0 = t_0 \le t_1 \le \ldots \le t_n= t$ of $[0,t]$ with mesh size going to $0$.
For $H = 1$ the sum telescopes to $X_t - X_0$. So in this case the identity follows directly from the definition.

Similarly for the Stratonovich integral, 
and essentially any reasonable kind of stochastic integral that is defined using a limit of "Riemann sums".

Comment: Well said. I think it is also worth mentioning that the identity in the OP is a one of the properties that we want to hold whenever we *define* a new version of integral.